# Using Scikit-learn on a csv dataset

Tags: python, arrays, scikit-learn

How do I apply `scikit-learn` to a `numpy` array with 4 columns each representing a different attribute? 
Basically, I'm wanting to teach it how to recognize a healthy patient from these 4 characteristics and then see if it can identify an abnormal one.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pipeline usually has the following steps:

1. Define a classifier/ regressor

`from sklearn import svm
clf = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001, C=100.)`

2. Fit the data

`clf.fit(X_train,y_train)`

Here X_train will your four column features and y_train will be the labels whether the patient is healthy.

3. Predict on new data

`y_pred = clf.prdict(X_test)`

[This tutorial](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html) is great starting point for you to get some basic idea about the pipeline.

Comment: Thank you! 
so would you define y_train as a column of 1's and 0's depending on whether of not the corresponding X_train row is normal and abnormal?

Comment: Yes you can binarize the y such as 1 means healthy and 0 patient for example.

Comment: @G.Bruce You can also put original labels in y while training. No need to convert to 0 or 1. They will be supported in scikit-learn.

Comment: wicked, thanks folks!

Answer (score 0):

Look into the `pandas` package which allows you to import CSV files into a dataframe. `pandas` is supported by `scikit-learn`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I was clear enough 

I have the CSV file in an array in a Numpy format (which i think is also supported by scikit-learn), but I don't understand how you actually process this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't mean to be pedantic or unhelpful, but have you looked at the sklearn tutorial yet? It covers a lot of this. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html

Comment: I have, and I can't seem to get started on what it is I want to do..
I'm quite new to coding, so sorry if I'm being particularly slow.

Comment: everything i have seen is asking for a predicted value, wheras I want to "plug in" this 4x200 array of normal patient data (4 different attributes), and I then want to be able to test a single patient and see if it is possible for it to be recognized as abnormal

does that make sense?